# how to use a custom PAM before asking for a password in the login screen (Fedora 35)

Tags: fedora, pam

I have developed a PAM module to use my fingerprint scanner for login. I tested it in ubuntu 18. in Ubuntu, I changed the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file and added this line at the first line:

```
auth    sufficient   /usr/local/lib/libpam_myscanner.so
```

But in Fedora 35, I added this line at the first line of many files, but nothing happened.
When I want to run a command with `sudo`, it asks me to authenticate with the scanner.

How can I add my PAM module before asking for a login password?

files that I changed currently:

```
login, system-auth, password-auth, gdm-password, sudo
```

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov how can I check it?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I did what you said, but nothing happened.

Comment: The journal output of the pam login might have some information.

Comment: @jsbillings I wrote many log messages in my code. But it prints nothing.

Comment: Then it isn’t being run.  BTW, you probably want it in password-auth, which is included from gdm-password.

Comment: @jsbillings I don't know how to get it run. I wrote it in every single file in /etc/pam.d/* but nothing happened. It just works for running commands with sudo in bash or unlocking administrative features in setting menus

Comment: Don’t put it in every file, just the one you want to test.  That way you know when it works which instance works.  Also, PAM runs through each sub stack linearly, so if there is an ‘auth’ line above that succeeds and it has “sufficient” or “required” then it won’t get to your step.

Comment: @jsbillings I test it one by one and again not working. I think it relate to sssd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ldd and found my pam module access to a shared library under my user path (/home/user). In Fedora and CentOS, SELinux prevented my pam module from accessing that shared library under that path.